# Error when trying to deploy my React app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, web-applications, deploying

So I am new in this coding with React. I wanted to deploy my App to heroku but I am getting this error shown in the picture.

[image: Error logs]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Also, there is probably more useful information about what you've shown us. When you [edit] your question to replace the image with text, please include the _full_ error message.

Comment: Thank you Chris I am new around here. When I tried to copy and paste the logs it looked very weird that is why I put screenshot of it. I found the fix to my problem and It works fine now. Adding these in package.json scripts fixed it. "start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",

Comment: "When I tried to copy and paste the logs it looked very weird that is why I put screenshot of it"—you can paste them as code. Paste, then select and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. "I found the fix to my problem and It works fine now"—great! Please consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help others with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

"start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start", 
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 
Adding these two to the package json and including npm and node as engines fixes my problem.